# Design Require Creating Displaying User Information

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to display a user information with property Id, FirstName, LastName and Email. I would like to know whats the best way, where should i define this property in the Interface or in the Class. Also i want to know where all i can use the Interface in the above scenario. For e.g i can inherit my class with the interface and implement all members of the interface. Can i also use my Interface in the main program or controller.

If some one can provide an example would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The best option is to use approach that is already used within your project for displaying all other information. It also depends on your storage approach, testing approach, etc. You did not even specify whether it is a web project or windows project.

Comment: Hi Andrey, it does not matter its a web or windows I want the best design for this so tomorrow I add any new property I don't have to change much on my design.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to use interface, you should use class for data transfer/view model objects.
It's simpler and does not have any immediate disadvantages.

The question does not give enough information on why you are considering using interface.

Comment: Actually I was attending interview and some one asked me to do it with interface and I wanted to get it done in the right way. He told me to use classes, Interface and do it. So wanted to know if in a scenario we have to use both where will we define the properties ? I guess here examples will be more helpful.

Comment: This is a very wide question, and as such, better learned from books/blogs/articles, than on StackOverflow. I would be just repeating a lot of information that is already widely available.